# Stripe with IDEAL specific Integration in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, stripe-payments

Tried working with the below code but it accepts all payments but wants IDEAL specific
card acceptance in Card Widget
[image: CardWidgetPicture]

Add Card.xml

```
<com.stripe.android.view.CardInputWidget
            android:id="@+id/cardInputWidget"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Java Code:

```
CardInputWidget cardInputWidget = findViewById(R.id.cardInputWidget);
    PaymentMethodCreateParams.Card card = cardInputWidget.getPaymentMethodCard();

    if (card != null) {
        PaymentMethod.BillingDetails billingDetails =
                new PaymentMethod.BillingDetails.Builder()
                        .build();
        // Create SetupIntent confirm parameters with the above
        PaymentMethodCreateParams paymentMethodParams = PaymentMethodCreateParams
                .create(card, billingDetails);
        
        if(paymentConfirmVM.setupIntentClientSecret.get()!=null) {
            ConfirmSetupIntentParams confirmParams = ConfirmSetupIntentParams
                    .create(paymentMethodParams, paymentConfirmVM.setupIntentClientSecret.get());
            stripe.confirmSetupIntent(this, confirmParams);
        }else{
            getViewModel().setIsLoading(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "wants IDEAL specific card acceptance" what does that mean?

Comment: IDEAL is a payment method/Card the Stripe widget used to accept card, should either accept only this card or accept payment only to this card is the requirement